# Post deleted as Copy-pasta by a moderator

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, plagiarism

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64475886/5675325) was deleted with the justification

> Copy-pasta with no original work from linked page.

I flagged it with moderator intervention with the reason

> This was closed with the justification "Copy-pasta" and I reference in
> the question [answer] I'm grabbing the information from the mentioned
> source, in particular the affirmations it has in it. I see no reason
> to delete it.

which was rejected due to

> Please review our attribution and referencing requirements:
> https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

In the referencing page it states

- Provide a link to the original page or answer -> which I did
- Quote only the relevant portion -> no quote format since it isn't exactly word by word translation but I state the affirmations and the images come from there (which is a common way of quoting in articles too)
- Provide the name of the original author -> I edited the answer to include it once the moderator CodyGray told me who was the author.

To me it's obvious I didn't intend to take credit for this but found value in that work.

---

**Here's the post of you're not able to see:**

> In [this website](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/) you're able to see truth tables. From looking at them, it's easily picked up the affirmations the author dorey presents in it
>
> - **== (negated: !=)**, using two equals signs for JavaScript equality testing, some funky conversions take place
>
> [image]
>
> - **=== (negated: !==)**, using three equals signs for JavaScript equality testing, everything is as is. Nothing gets converted before
>   being evaluated.
>
> [image]
>
> In other words, always use 3 equals unless you have a good reason to
> use 2.
>
> If you will, there's also a unified version of it [here](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/unified/)
>
> [image]

Comment: You cited your source but didn’t quote it.  I also don’t see a single sentence you wrote that was not from your source.

Comment: @SecurityHound I didn't use the quote format but I state the content comes from there and I specify the affirmations and truth tables. There's no other images or affirmations in it

Comment: You have to quote and cite your source but also write something that isn’t taken from the source.  Just copying and pasting content isn’t that helpful.

Comment: Not to mention you didn't really add any new information as a new answer on a ___old___ question that has 10 answers already...

Comment: The author's name is "dorey"; see https://github.com/dorey/JavaScript-Equality-Table. The referencing guidelines on that page seem pretty clear to me.

Comment: It combines more than one source even though one is linked in the initial source and it doesn't use the entire content present in it

Comment: @Cerbrus I disagree. Which other answers use the truth tables for example?

Comment: @CodyGray the used link was different than that one you're sharing

Comment: The source is the same.

Comment: Yes. I did around 1-2 seconds of digging to find the author's name. (Their full name could have been different than the name in the URL slug. In this case, it wasn't.)

Comment: @CodyGray I only saw the shared page

Comment: @Tiago - You could edit and improve your answer but take all the feedback into consideration.  Copying and pasting content into an answer isn’t considered helpful.

Comment: @SecurityHound now that I know the author name I edited the answer and included that information in it

Comment: @CodyGray the name of the author was included in the answer after you stating who it was. It is not my intent to take credit for the author's work. If that's not clear, I'm willing to know what else must be done.

Comment: From the link in your answer : *Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own ..*

Comment: Sorry? Copy-pasta? Is that the Italian word for plagiarism?

Comment: @JK: Slang, but it appears to be an official English word (slightly different spelling): *[copypasta](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/copypasta#Noun)* - *"(Internet slang) A block of text which has been copied and pasted from somewhere else."*. The (real) origin seems [to be unknown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copypasta#Etymology).

Answer (score 26):

That 8-year-old question had 10 answers already. Everything you need to know about equality comparison is already in there.

You copy-pasted a website into an answer. You didn't add any significant writing, you even verbatim copied their explanations.
That's blatant plagiarism, even if you linked to the source.

Comment: I'm stating the information comes from there and which information.

Comment: That's not good enough. What you _could_ have done, is insert the tables, link to the source, and add your own explanation to these tables. What you _have_ done, is: _"Look at these truth tables I copied from this website: <copy-pasta>"_

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 - So your answer is the search result of a search engine?  We need detailed answers not just copy and pasted content.